# Obtaining matches for faces\ts with only a count of 1 in SOLR

Tags: java, solr

I am writing a testng test that does a SOLR query and gives a facet field (in this case it is taxid).  I can get the facet results for entries with each taxid that looks similar to this:

```
    "123456780",
    104059,
    "123456781",
    76777,
    "123456782",
    72797,
    ...
```

the values in quotes are the IDs and the other numbers are the count.  What I want to do is find the ones with a count of 1.  If I could have it return the facet value in ascending order that would be good.  Specifying in the query to return only facets with count of 1 would be better.

I could feasibly read them all into a Java array and sort or find which have a value of 1 (as a count) but there are "numFound": 11952086.  Eleven million is too many to parse.  Is there a way to return the count ascending or just return values which have a count of 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am fairly sure that there is no way to return facet result satisfying condition on count.

But following may help you.

Facet result can be sorted using facet.sort=count parameter. It will sort facet result in descending order of count.

```
curl -XGET 'http://172.26.98.10:8886/solr/SF_CaseComments/select?q=lock&rows=0&facet=true&facet.field=CreatedById&facet.sort=count&facet.limit=-1&facet.mincount=1&wt=json'
```

You may ignore result till you find 1 and process there onwards.

Comment: So keep getting more results until facet is 1, then and keep storing until it is 0, right?

Comment: yes, if you use facet.mincount=1 parameter then 0 count will not be in result anyway.